# my android app in kotlin keeps on crashing, and it has been showing me this in the log

Tags: android, kotlin

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.h2, PID: 13228
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.h2/com.example.h2.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class linearLoyout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class linearLoyout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class linearLoyout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.linearLoyout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.h2-LZ1S58avR3GXvrmItkNZrg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.h2-LZ1S58avR3GXvrmItkNZrg==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.h2.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.kt:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)

Comment: Something is looking for `linearLoyout`. Find your xml layout file for the first activity, check it. Include it in the question if you're sure it's correct.

Comment: this is where your error is SecondActivity.kt:10. Line 10 of your SecondActivity

Answer (score 2):

On line 17, "android.view.linearLoyout", it seems like you typed the wrong letter? I think you meant linearLayout not linear Loyout. If you changed that then it may work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually find your error at the top of the crash log. In your case its found with the following line:

```
Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class linearLoyout at
```

The line state that the crash happened because the class `LinearLoyout` could not be inflated. The class will be located on line 2 of the XML file.

read up on crashes and how to read the logs here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash

Like Robotic Reaper said, "LinearLoyout" should be "LinearLayout".